# How to count letters in string array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I need to create a method, which takes `string[]` and only returns words that are 5 letters or shorter.

I am very new to programming, please help.

Comment: Can you provide the code you've written, thus far?

Comment: What's in the `string[]`? Is each element of the array (i.e., each string) a word, or a series of words?

Comment: @benc 
 class ShortWords
        {

            public int ShortWrods_m (params string[] input)
            {
             
                var count = 0;
                foreach (string vstup_ in vstup)
                {
                    count = count+1;
                }
                return count; 
            }
I am aware that this code only returns the number of words of input.

Comment: @JoeSewell
It's a word like "Portugal".

Comment: How do you define "word"? Does it need to exist in some repository of valid words? What if there are numbers in the "word"? Do those count against the "5 letters or less" rule? Or do you just mean you want to return the items in the array that are 5 characters or less? Please be more specific in your requirements, and show what you have so far so we can see where it's not working.

Comment: Your code won't compile (what is `vstup`? where did it come from?) - Also, your code can be replaced with `var count = input.Length;`.

Comment: Whether you are new to programming or not, we all face programming problems that we don't know how to solve.  The solution is always the same: **find a simpler problem that you do know how to solve, and start by solving that**.  So, what's a simpler problem that you know how to solve? For example, can you write a method that takes a string array and returns *all of them*?   That's a simpler problem, and if you cannot solve it, then you cannot solve the harder problem.  So start by solving the simpler problem.  If that one is too hard, **find an even simpler problem**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to make sure that the word contains only 5 letters or less, meaning you want to exclude punctuation marks from the length of the word, you could regex strip out all non-letter characters from the word before checking if the remaining length of the word is 5 or less.

The Regex object in the method will strip off all non letters from the word and then it checks the length of what remains, but you add the original word back to the resulting list for display.

You can try something like the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] words = new string[] {
            "I", "need", "to", "create", "a", "method", "which", "takes", "string[]", 
            "and", "only", "returns", "words", "that", "are", "5", "letters", "or", "shorter",
            "aren't"
        };

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", Get5LetterWords(words)));

    }

    public static string[] Get5LetterWords(string[] words)
    {
        Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z]");
        List<string> _5LetterWords = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            string word = rgx.Replace(words[i], "");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(word) && word.Length <=5 )
            {
                _5LetterWords.Add(words[i]);
            }

        }

        return _5LetterWords.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Results:

```
I, need, to, a, which, takes, and, only, words, that, are, or, aren't
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i7npOx)

Comment: You really should use a Unicode character category such as `\P{L}` to get letters from other languages.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments about letters, and using Unicode Categories to define letters:

```
public int ShortWordCount(params string[] input) => input.Where(w => { var lc = w.Where(c => Char.IsLetter(c)).Count(); return lc <= 5 && lc > 0; }).Count();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use LINQ and the Where function to filter out the results:

```
var shortWordsList = originalArray.ToList().Where(e => e.Length <= 5);
```

Just copy it, I have flagged your question anyway :)

Comment: Given the question he's asking (and considering the context) I'd expect them to be able to do a for loop and check word by word. Even though your response would be fine, I don't think this is what he's looking for. However, this seems like a homework question, which all in all suggests that this question should be closed.

Comment: This method includes will include punctuation symbols in the results, whereas the OP specified *"5 letters or shorter"*. The word "aren't" only contains 5 letters, but would not be included in these results.